# Summation of an array of max values in excel?

Tags: excel-formula, sum, max, array-formulas

Suppose I have the following data in cells A1:A3

```
A1 = 1
A2 = 3
A3 = 5
```

I'd like to write a formula that sums the difference between the number in the cell and 2. If the difference is negative, then take 0. I tried the following CSE/array formula:

```
{=sum(max(A1:A3-2,0))}
```

Excel evaluates the formula as follows:

```
sum(max({1-2,3-2,5-2},0)) = sum(max({-1,1,3},0)) = sum(max(-1,1,3,0)) = sum(3) = 3
```

I'd like to write a formula that is evaluated as follows:

```
sum({max(-1,0),max(1,0),max(3,0)}) = sum({0,1,3}) = 4
```

Obviously one approach to this problem is to carry out a second computation in column B such that:

```
 B1 = max(A1-2,0) = max(-1,0) = 0
 B2 = max(A2-2,0) = max( 1,0) = 1
 B3 = max(A3-2,0) = max( 3,0) = 3
```

then my target formula is:

```
= sum(B1:B3) = 4
```

However, I'd like to know: **is there a way to do this in a single cell using array formula?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this? Instead of trying to use `MAX`, just use `SUMPRODUCT`. If the difference is negative, `A1:A3-2>0` evaluates to `FALSE`, which is equivalent to multiplying the difference by `0`.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A3-2)*(A1:A3-2>0))
```

[image]

Comment: thats a great way to do it, much simpler than what I was thinking